# List Page:Configurable Product: getPrice: in Magento 2

Tags: configurable-product, price, magento2.2.2, special-price

`In List Page :`

1) How the Configurable product price and special price  is displayed ?

2) Which price it will take to display on the product in List page ? and

3) Which file is responsible to display price of the configurable product

Comment: Please enable the template path hints and check which files are responsible

Comment: I need to get price of the configurable product

Answer (score 0):

Please find following your question answer

## 1 : It will display Price like $price = $price - $SpecialPrice if there is set special price.

## 2 : It will display lowest price from assigned simple product

## 3 : Following files :

vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml

Thanks